# Search multiple strings by using reference template and produce a constant number for that string

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

In sheet 1 I have:

```
Sno Description
1   uproc_incident_X
2   sys_win_disque_e
3   sys_unx_disk
4   process_unx_event_wait
5   process_unx_Uproc
6   process_win_china
7   http_get_zom_facturation
8   http_get_zom_stars
9   services_win_TaskScheduler
10  check_sos_out
11  check_LOG
12  app_unx_check
13  app_unx_11000
14  app_win_mqmngr
15  app_lnx_log_syslog
16  app_ora_alertlog
17  ora_tbs_usage
```

sheet 2 contains:

```
Sno Description Time
1   uproc   20
2   sys_win 20
3   sys_unx 15
4   process 12
5   http_get    12
6   services    10
7   check   10
8   app_unx 15
9   app_win 15
10  app_lnx 10
11  app_ora 10
12  ora 10
```

I want a formula to write in sheet 1 next to description by matching my sheet 2 with sheet 1 and provide the exact match number result as in sheet 2 in sheet 1 so the final result should look like this:

```
Sno Description Time
1   uproc_incident_X    20
2   sys_win_disque_e    20
3   sys_unx_disk    15
4   process_unx_event_wait  12
5   process_unx_Uproc   12
6   process_win_china   12
7   http_get_zom_facturation    12
8   http_get_zom_stars  12
9   services_win_TaskScheduler  10
10  check_sos_out   10
11  check_LOG   10
12  app_unx_check   15
13  app_unx_11000   15
14  app_win_mqmngr  15
15  app_lnx_log_syslog  10
16  app_ora_alertlog    10
17  ora_tbs_usage   10
```

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a mapping table as shown in Column C and then in D2 and copied down:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,'sheet 2'!B:C,2,0)
```

[image: SO32143810 example]

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion , i would have a challenge here in C column you have manually filled the template wherein i would require a formula that searches in Bcolumn and provide appropriate search result in C column ?